# I'm not able to isolate Array in OCaml from modifying

Tags: arrays, ocaml, mutable

[Here](https://github.com/amorphine/cyberdawn/blob/master/serv.ml) is the full code. I'll try to show some pieces. I'm writing a tic tac toe server working via telnet. This is a representation of game board

```
let empty_board = [|
                [|EMPTY; EMPTY; EMPTY|];
                [|EMPTY; EMPTY; EMPTY|];
                [|EMPTY; EMPTY; EMPTY|]|]
```

It's used only once by `Array.copy` to pass players descriptors and new board in game loop:

```
let prepare_game_process pair_of_players= 
 pair_of_players >>= fun (player1, player2) ->  
 send_to_client player1 "You play for X";
 send_to_client player2 "You play for O";
 let new_board = Array.copy empty_board in
 game_loop player1 player2 new_board
```

But every time new game begins all changes in game_loop are reflected to original empty_board:

```
let make_move x y board token=
 board.(y).(x) <- token;
 board
```

I looked through the code billion times but I couldn't see the reason at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only copying the outer array, not the individual row arrays.

Comment: Thank you to help me again. Do you mean I should use Array.map for "deep copy"? Inner arrays are presented in a copy as refs, right? That's why they change, do they?

Comment: Yes, although in this case it would be easier to make `empty_board` a function rather than a value. Or, you could change `make_move` to copy the two arrays (row and board) being changed, making the board immutable.